# JavaScript - extract folder names

Tags: windows, file, directory, javascript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript.

Given a local machine's folder path (Windows), I was wondering how you can extract the names of all the possible folders in the current path, without the knowledge of how many folders there are or what they are called.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a little script to get you started with FileSystemObject in conjuction with JScript:

```
var fso   = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var path  = "%ProgramFiles%";

var programFiles = fso.GetFolder(shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(path));
var subFolders   = new Enumerator(programFiles.SubFolders);

while (!subFolders.atEnd())
{
  var subFolder = subFolders.item();
  WScript.Echo(subFolder.Name);
  subFolders.moveNext();
}
```

Call that with csript.exe on the command line:

```
cscript subfolders.js
```

The [Windows Script 5.6 Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=01592C48-207D-4BE1-8A76-1C4099D7BBB9&displaylang=en) holds all the details you need on this topic (and many others). Download it and have it around, it is really helpful. On Windows systems, a little knowledge of FileSystemObject and it's relatives really can save the day.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this via Javascript in a browser as the JS doesn't have that kind of access to the file system from a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the script will execute in a context where it makes sense to try and access the local hard drives (e.g. in cscript or classic ASP), your best bet is the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing JavaScript in a web browser then you can't, because in this scenario JavaScript has no access to the local file system for security reasons.